# Send javascript array to php using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

How can I send javascript array to php?
I have using JSON.stringify to every javascript array and catch the array using json_decode, but stil not working.

I don't know how to do it anymore. Any suggestion?

In JS :

```
 jarak = new Array(koordinat_kapal_threat.length);
 for (var i = 0; i < jarak.length; i++) {
     jarak[i] = new Array(koordinat_kapal_threat.length);
     for (var j = 0; j < jarak.length; j++) {
         if (i === j) {
             jarak[i][j] = 0;
         } else {
             var distance = getDistance(koordinat_kapal_threat[i], koordinat_kapal_threat[j]);
             jarak[i][j] = distance;
         }
     }
 }

 // buat array visibilitas
 visibilitas = new Array(koordinat_kapal_threat.length);
 for (var i = 0; i < visibilitas.length; i++) {
     visibilitas[i] = new Array(koordinat_kapal_threat.length);
     for (var j = 0; j < visibilitas.length; j++) {
         if (i === j) {
             visibilitas[i][j] = 0;
         } else {
             var visibilitas_kapal = 1 / jarak[i][j];
             visibilitas[i][j] = visibilitas_kapal;
         }
     }
 }

 var tau = 0.01;
 // buat array feromon
 feromon = new Array(koordinat_kapal_threat.length);
 for (var i = 0; i < feromon.length; i++) {
     feromon[i] = new Array(koordinat_kapal_threat.length);
     for (var j = 0; j < feromon.length; j++) {
         feromon[i][j] = tau;
     }
 }

 var banyak_semut = koordinat_kapal_threat.length;

 var a = JSON.stringify(koordinat_kapal_threat);
 var b = JSON.stringify(jarak);
 var c = JSON.stringify(visibilitas);
 var d = JSON.stringify(feromon);

 var data = {
     koordinat_kapal_threat: a,
     jarak: b,
     visibilitas: c,
     feromon: d,
     banyak_semut: banyak_semut
 };




 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     url: "algoritmaAnt.php",
     data: data,
     success: function (result) {
         var data = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
         var jalur = new google.maps.Polyline({
             path: data,
             geodesic: true,
             strokeColor: '#FCFF49', strokeOpacity: 1.0,
             strokeWeight: 2,
         });
         jalur.setMap(map);
     }
 });
```

In PHP :

```
$koordinat_kapal_threat =json_decode($_POST['koordinat_kapal_threat']);   
$jarak = json_decode($_POST['jarak']); 
$visibilitas =json_decode($_POST['visibilitas']); 
$feromon = json_decode($_POST['feromon']); 
$banyak_semut = $_POST['banyak_semut'];
```

Comment: We can't possibly know why something doesn't work if you don't provide the relevant code along with a bit of explanation of what array you are trying to send

Comment: Are you using ***jQuery*** or what to send and get data...?

Comment: I have updated my question @charlietfl

Comment: Not JQuery bro @ArunaWarnasooriya

Comment: Actually don't need to convert to, or decode from json at all. `var data ={ property_1:[1,4,5]}` can be received as array in `$_POST['property_1]`.

Comment: Also add an ajax error handler and check your browser console for errors

Answer (score 0):

> This is the Simple Way, you need to use JSON.stringify for encoding Data to JSON, similarly use json_decode for extract the data

**JavaScript**
     var a=JSON.stringify(your_array_name);
     var b = JSON.stringify(jarak);   // your Array

```
// Ajax Call
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     async:true,
     url: "algoritmaAnt.php",
     data: {'data1':a,'data2':b},
     success: function (result) {
             // your success operation;
      }
});
```

**PHP Code**

```
$jarak = json_decode($_POST['data1']);
$data2 = json_decode($_POST['data2']);

print_r($jarak); 
print_r($data2);
```

Comment: How can I send multiple array as I give in example?

Comment: Edited for your requirement, in ajax call data also use JSON method, so you can append the data using separater

Comment: In success ajax, how to catch the result?
Is my example true or something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No need to stringify arrays. Change your data var as below

```
var data = {
     koordinat_kapal_threat: koordinat_kapal_threat,
     jarak: jarak,
     visibilitas: visibilitas,
     feromon: feromon,
     banyak_semut: banyak_semut
 };
```